# Allow only authorized endpoints to send events to event grid

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid, azure-authentication, azure-security

I am working on a project which uses Azure Event Grid where a web application sends a custom event to event grid and a web-hook within a separate application is used to subscribe to these events.

It looks like it is secure on the web-hook side since only you can add the specific web hook to be used as the event grid subscription.
However, I did not find much information on how to restrict event grid to receive events only from a specific endpoint. Right now it only provides you with an endpoint and a topic key which must be used when sending events to the topic. If someone manages to get hold of both the endpoint and the token key then "malicious events" can be sent to the event grid.

Is there a way on how to restrict event grid to only accept events from a particular source, or is storing and retrieving the key from Key Vault, the most secure option available?

Comment: have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-domains

Answer (score 1):

When publishing messages to a topic, you can [authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication#custom-topic-publishing) either by using a key or a SAS token.

1. [Using a key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication#key-authentication) is the simplest way to authenticate, but like you've mentioned, if stolen, could lead to malicious events being sent.

   One way to secure this approach is to use KeyVault as you've mentioned. Clients could securely connect to KeyVault using [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) (if running on Azure) or the [Client Credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).
2. [Using SAS tokens is the recommended way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication#sas-tokens) to secure your publish endpoint. For this, you will have to generate tokens as and when needed using a key (The same key as in 1)

   In this approach, you could have an API (like an Azure Function for example) which generates the SAS tokens on behalf of your clients. This API would still need the key (which could be in KeyVault) to generate the SAS tokens.
3. Another approach would be to have an API which could forward events to Event Grid, upon authentication/authorization. This API would still need access to the key.

   This could be achieved in a couple of ways as well like

   - [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview)
   - [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) using the [Azure Event Grid Publish connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureeventgridpublish/)
   - [Azure APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts) (in case you are already using one)

Comment: If I use the keyvault or MSI; is there anyway to automatically rotate keys, and have the publishing application automatically pick up the new keys.

I wonder about giving the MSI direct access to read the key, but couldn't see a) which permissions where required; or b) how to read the key programmatically.

I don't see the advantage to using keyvault in this instance if the MSI can be given only read access to the keys in the first place.

You could use a SAS is great but I can't see how to create one pragmatically without giving the system the key, which defeats the object